# PyCharm не видит методы модуля QtWidgets

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

вот возник вопрос на счет [pycharm](/questions/tagged/pycharm). Начал работать с графическим интерфейсом [qt](/questions/tagged/qt) и при импортирование модуля `QtWidgets` все импортируется но не высвечивает методы классов через точку, при этом если все прописывать вручную то все работает.

Когда подключаю шрифт и цвет, то все работает.

[image: Не выводит строку]

[image: Шрифт]

Answer (score 1):

Доброго дня. Недавно столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Судя из того, что я понял, PyCharm не смог правильно распарсить библиотеку PyQt5 и получился неправильный `skeletons`, причем, судя по всему, у них эта проблема тянется еще с 2012 года с разными версиями. На разных форумах пишется, что проблема именно с версии PyQt5.3 и далее, т.е. можно взять готовый скелетон с более ранней версии (к примеру PyQt5.2) и скопировать к себе (по пути `.PyCharm2016.1/system/python_stubs/-*********/`).

Вот еще способы, которые я нашел для решения данной проблемы:

1. Можно указывать вместо строки `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets` строку `from PyQt5.uic.Compiler.qtproxies import QtWidgets`. Тогда все методы внутри класса определяются. Но это довольно-таки локальное решение.
2. Более глобальное решение. Вручную создать `skeleton` библиотеки PyQt. Для этого необходимо выполнить несколько команд (в моём случае 4). Привожу пример для среды Linux, в Windows аналогично:

   ```
   ==> python3 generator3.py -x -d ~/.PyCharm2016.1/system/python_stubs/-1247971765/ PyQt5 <br>
   ==> python3 generator3.py -x -d ~/.PyCharm2016.1/system/python_stubs/-1247971765/ PyQt5.QtWidgets <br>
   ==> python3 generator3.py -x -d ~/.PyCharm2016.1/system/python_stubs/-1247971765/ PyQt5.QtCore <br>
   ==> python3 generator3.py -x -d ~/.PyCharm2016.1/system/python_stubs/-1247971765/ PyQt5.QtGui <br><br>
   ```

   Хочу обратить внимание, что после пути, PyQt5, PyQt5.QtWidgets и т.д. пишется через пробел.

P.S. Файл generator3.py находится по пути `PyCharm2016.1/helpers/generator3.py`

Пример для Windows:

```
==> python "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.1\helpers\generator3.py" -x -d "C:\Users\user\.PyCharm50\system\python_stubs\324234324" PyQt5
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос задан давно, на него дан ответ, но столкнувшись, недавно, с такой же проблемой (отвутствие автокомплита, PyCharm 2017, Linux Mint 18.1), начал лопатить инет, везде были советы, которые не помогали, переставил Qt, PyQt, SIP и все что только можно ...
Решилось все просто. Как оказалось, без созданного проекта, если перетаскивать откуда-нибудь в окно чарма файл с кодом, автокомплит не работает, ну не работает и все тут... библы подхватывает, все запускается, но упорно не автокомплитится. Совет - не ленитесь, создавайте проекты.
Совет глупый, но может кому поможет.